# GNOME shell laggy on HP Notebook (w/ Pentium N3710 processor)

Tags: gnome, intel, cpu

I have an HP Notebook with the following specs:

- 8GB RAM.
- 128GB SSD.
- Intel HD Graphics 405 (Integrated).
- Quad Core Intel Pentium N3710 processor (2.56GHz).

  From the time I first bought it, I kept cycling between distros (Ubuntu, Kali, openSUSE and Fedora). But with all of them, I chose the GNOME DE.
  However, I noticed that the GNOME shell was quite laggy for me. Animations weren't that smooth, considerable lag when clicking the "Show Applications" button, etc. At first, I thought it was a problem with my graphics card. But then, I saw my friend use it on his laptop (also with an Intel integrated graphics card), and it was considerably much smoother for him (his processor was an Intel i3 Quad Core).

  Few days later, I tested out Ubuntu (with the Unity DE) and Kali Linux (With KDE) in a live session, and both of those worked super smooth. No lag at all. Currently, I'm running Fedora 27, because I've found that this had the smoothest performance with GNOME. Is this a problem with my processor? And is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: Don't use shell. Shell requires dedicated gpu. Instead try Unity or Ubuntu-Mate.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam But my friend uses it too. And even his laptop uses an integrated graphics card.

Comment: Hardware profile is different. So it may appear that shell is working well on same sort of hardware but it isn't. Beside for shell you need at least Nvidia. Instead try Unity with xorg. It's fast, really fast.